# Dojo: dijit.form.filteringselect dynamically add options from Json

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am getting data from json file, now i want to add it to filteringselect. i tried below code but its not adding, please help me

```
 HTML code==
        <select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect"
                id="education"></select>

        Javascrip code==
            request.get("/json/education.json", {
                            handleAs: "json"
                        }).then(function(data) {

                            var node = dijit.byId('education');
                            dojo.forEach(data.items, function(desc, index){     
                                node.addOption({
                                     label: desc.name,
                                     value: desc.value 
                                     });
                            });

                        },
                        function(error){});


    Json code

    {
        "title":"Education",
        "items":[
    {"name":"Select Education","value":"0"},
    {"name":"B.A", "value":"1"},
    {"name":"B.Sc" ,"value":"2"},
    ...........................
```

Comment: What does your dojoConfig look like ?

Answer (score 2):

The store of FilteringSelect can be set dynamically, based on the ajax call.

```
var str = new dojo.store.Memory(optionData);
dijit.byId('widgetId').set('store',str);
```

But, your json data must be like this:-

```
var optionData={
                data:[
                   {id:'aaaaaa',name:'aaaaaa'},
                   {id:'bbbbbb',name:'bbbbbb'}
                  ]
               };
```

The above example will actually replace the store. If, the new data from ajax call need to be appended to the existing options, then

```
 //str is the existing store of FilteringSelect field above
 dojo.forEach(result.data, function(optionSet, index){     
                str.add(optionSet);
 });
```

***Note to remember:*** 'addOption' is available only for Select. Not for FilteringSelect.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
dijit.byId("select_id").store.root.add(dojo.create("option",{ value: "some", innerHTML: "label of option"}));
```

To remove the existing elements did just that:

```
var size = dijit.byId("select_id").store.root.removeChild.length;    
for(var i=size; i>=0; i--){   dijit.byId("select_id").store.root.removeChild(dijit.byId("select_id").store.root.children[size-1]);
}
```